# Accept a file via API Gateway POST method

Tags: post, file-upload, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, multipartform-data

I'm building a serverless application which consists of an API Gateway and a Lambda. What I want to do is perform a POST request with a json body AND a file object. The Lambda will read the file object and based on the params in the json body perform some processing on the file and give back results in json format.

Example:

```
/POST

body {
    "id": "C123456",
    "format": "echo10",
    "file": <xml file that the user uploads>
}
```

I'm using the [`LambdaRestAPI`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.LambdaRestApi.html) construct with `proxy` set as `True`.

I've looked around, learned about using [binaryMediaTypes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html), but don't understand how I can get the file AND the json object at the same time.

Another way I've seen is getting the Lambda to get a PreSignedURL for uploading the file to s3, which I don't want to do because 1. I don't want to *save* the file, 2. it just complicates the architecture.

How can I get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Look here. [AWS docs](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/) . The file size limit for API gateway is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html)